# How to not repeat same phrases in a list?

Tags: python

I created a password generator but the problem is if I requested big number of passwords, some passwords are repeated.
I'm trying to find a way to replace the repeated passwords by non-repeated ones, and I can't figure it out.
Here's the code:

```
import random
import string
import os

chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
number = int(input('Enter the number of passwords you want: '))
length = int(input('Enter the length of the passwords: '))
print('Do you want to save the output in a file?(Y, n) ')
answer = input()
if answer == 'Y':
    fname = input('Enter file name: ') + '.txt'
    current_path = os.getcwd()
    fpath = os.path.join(current_path, fname)
    lst = []
    for pwd in range(number):
        password = ''
        for c in range(length):
            password += random.choice(chars)
        print(password)
        lst.append(password)
    with open(fpath, 'w') as file:
        for item in lst:
            file.write(item)
            file.write('\n')

elif answer == 'n':
    for pwd in range(number):
        password = ''
        for c in range(length):
            password += random.choice(chars)
        print(password)
else:
    print('Couldn\'t understand that')
    quit()
```

Comment: You need to store the passwords you've already generated, and check for each new one whether it's a repeat.

Comment: how about something like uuid?

Comment: `lst = set()` if you want unique values

Answer (score 1):

Create a list/set of already used passwords. Your code makes that a bit tricky because each created password is always instantly used. So you're gonna have to create a list where you store them in. Here is how you could do it (only the console print case):

```
import random
import string
import os

chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
number = int(input('Enter the number of passwords you want: '))
length = int(input('Enter the length of the passwords: '))
print('Do you want to save the output in a file?(Y, n) ')
answer = input()
if answer == 'Y':
    ...
elif answer == 'n':
    already_used_pws = set()
    while len(already_used_pws) < number:
        password = ''
        for c in range(length):
            password += random.choice(chars)
        if password in already_used_pws:
            continue
        print(password)
        already_used_pws.add(password)
else:
    print('Couldn\'t understand that')
    quit()
```

`continue` skips the iteration and doesnt print and add this `password` if it was used before, so it keeps being in the while loop until enough different passwords were generated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't reccomend store a password as plaintext because is easily accessible. Linux for exemple use crypt(5) to apply changes and store password in /etc/shadow like a hash. Just like I reccomend!

The [Hash Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) is a one way function with trap door to reverse or in other words: A function that can be computed by a string but cannot be reverted again to a string.

So to answer you the [set()](https://realpython.com/python-sets/) structure can store only unique values so you won't be repeat ones pass using this structure.

I refactor a little your code, keep learning:

```
import random, hashlib
from string import ascii_letters, digits, punctuation


def main():
    """Genertae random strings of char"""

    def get_input():
        number = int(input('Enter the number of passwords you want: '))
        length = int(input('Enter the length of the passwords: '))

        answer = input('Do you want to save the output in a file?(Y, n) ')
        assert (answer == 'n' or answer == 'Y')
        return number, length, answer


    def generate_pass(number):
        ret = set()
        for pwd in range(number):
            password = ''
            chars = ascii_letters + digits + punctuation
            
            for _ in range(length):
                password += random.choice(chars)
            # or using list compreension
            # password = [random.choice(chars) for _ in range(length)]

            def hashed(text):
                return hashlib.sha224(text.encode('UTF-8')).hexdigest()

            password = "".join(password)
            password = str([password,hashed(password)])
            print(password)
            ret.add(password)

        return ret

    def add_to_file(store, fname):
        path = os.getcwd()
        fpath = os.path.join(path, fname)
        
        with open(fpath, 'w') as file:
            for item in store:
                file.write(str(item))
                file.write('\n')

    number, length, answer = get_input()
    if answer == 'Y':
        fname = input('Enter file name: ') + '.txt'
        password = generate_pass(number)
        add_to_file(password, fname)

    elif answer == 'n':
        password = generate_pass(number)
    else:
        print('Couldn\'t understand that')
        quit()
main()
```

Comment: All that talk about not storing the passwords as plaintext... and then you store the passwords as plaintext.

Comment: Yep, just delete the password and they will not be stored, I code like a reference but if you have a paper, you can use instead!